# How to randomly set elements in numpy array to 0

Tags: python, numpy

First I create my array

```
myarray = np.random.random_integers(0,10, size=20)
```

Then, I want to set 20% of the elements in the array to 0 (or some other number). How should I do this? Apply a mask?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can calculate the indices with `np.random.choice`, limiting the number of chosen indices to the percentage:

```
indices = np.random.choice(np.arange(myarray.size), replace=False,
                           size=int(myarray.size * 0.2))
myarray[indices] = 0
```

Comment: Cool. I should also set `replace=False` for np.random.choice right? If I do not, some of the indices generated will be repeated

Comment: Yes. Updated my answer.

Comment: For arbitrarily shaped arrays we can use unravel_index: 
myarray[np.unravel_index(indices, myarray.shape)] = 0

Comment: @Holi 's comment is such a useful addition it should either be incorporated into this answer or made its own separate answer, IMO

Answer (score 4):

For others looking for the answer in case of nd-array, as proposed by user holi:

```
my_array = np.random.rand(8, 50)
indices = np.random.choice(my_array.shape[1]*my_array.shape[0], replace=False, size=int(my_array.shape[1]*my_array.shape[0]*0.2))
```

We multiply the dimensions to get an array of length dim1*dim2, then we apply this indices to our array:

```
my_array[np.unravel_index(indices, my_array.shape)] = 0
```

The array is now masked.

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.random.permutation` as random index generator, and take the first 20% of the index.

```
myarray = np.random.random_integers(0,10, size=20)
n = len(myarray)
random_idx = np.random.permutation(n)

frac = 20 # [%]
zero_idx = random_idx[:round(n*frac/100)]
myarray[zero_idx] = 0
```

Comment: DeprecationWarning: This function is deprecated. Please call randint(0, 10 + 1) instead. Now it is: myarray = np.random.randint(0,10, size=20)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 20% to be random:

```
random_list = []
array_len = len(myarray)

while len(random_list) < (array_len/5):
    random_int = math.randint(0,array_len)
    if random_int not in random_list:
        random_list.append(random_int)

for position in random_list:
    myarray[position] = 0

return myarray
```

This would ensure you definitely get 20% of the values, and RNG rolling the same number many times would not result in less than 20% of the values being 0.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your input numpy array is `A` and `p=0.2`. The following are a couple of ways to achieve this.

##### Exact Masking

```
ones = np.ones(A.size)
idx = int(min(p*A.size, A.size))
ones[:idx] = 0
A *= np.reshape(np.random.permutation(ones), A.shape)
```

##### Approximate Masking

This is commonly done in several denoising objectives, most notably the Masked Language Modeling in Transformers pre-training. Here is a more pythonic way of setting a certain proportion (say 20%) of elements to zero.

```
A *= np.random.binomial(size=A.shape, n=1, p=0.8)
```

**Another Alternative:**

```
A *= np.random.randint(0, 2, A.shape)
```