# how can I randomly change n-elements (continuous) of an array to 0?

Tags: python, numpy

My list has a `.shape` of `(139280,)`. I want to find a random 100 elements (in a row) and set them to `0`. What's the most Pythonic way to do that?

Comment: Get a random number between 0 and `len(yourlist) - 99` and then iterate the slice starting there?

Comment: Perfect - can you post as an answer and I will accept?

Comment: Be careful, Python lists don't have a `shape` attribute, nor do they really have "rows"!

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48536969/11301900.

Comment: @AMC, not exactly. My question is about continuous elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was:

```
    num_frames = int(samplerate / (1000 / ms_to_cut))
    start_frame = random.randint(buffer, len(audio_array) - num_frames - buffer)
    incomplete_audio_array = audio_array
    incomplete_audio_array[start_frame:start_frame + num_frames] = 0
```